# How to use http delete () in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, angular6

### myService.ts

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { Http, Response,Headers,RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
  import 'rxjs/Rx';
  import{Router} from'@angular/router';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
  @Injectable()
  export class ManageJobDeleteService{
    constructor(private http: Http,private router:Router){};
    DeleteRequestToAPI(post_jobs_id:string){
       let body = JSON.stringify({post_jobs_id:post_jobs_id});
       let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
       let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        console.log(body);
        console.log(options);
      return this.http.delete('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employer/post_jobs/',body,options)//HERE I AM GETTING ERROR
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
    }
   private extractData(res: Response){
      let body = res.json();
      console.log(body);
      return body || [];   
    }
    private handleError (error: any) {
      console.error(error);
      return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
  }
```

ERROR:

> Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.ts(2554).

Please tell me  how to pass both body and options using http delete request in Angular 6.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request

Answer (score 31, accepted):

there is no body argument on delete.

so, you need to remove body argument.

```
this.http.delete('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employer/post_jobs/',options)
```

[Reference](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient)

```
class HttpClient {
     delete(url: string, 
       options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; 
       observe?: HttpObserve; params... = {}): Observable<any>
}
```

**Edit: How can I pass post_jobs_id?**

you can use HttpParams:

```
let httpParams = new HttpParams().set('aaa', '111');
httpParams.set('bbb', '222');

let options = { params: httpParams };

this.http.delete('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employer/post_jobs/',options);
```

Comment: so how can i pass post_jobs_id ?

Comment: @lpd before that , you need to inject `HttpClient` instead of `Http` as it has been deprecated in later versions of Angular. You also need to import `HttpClientModule` in your app.module

Comment: @KonradViltersten what do you mean with this comment? I couldn't get it

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu Sorry. It's a reference to Yoda, the short, green Jedi warrior in Star Wars. Yoda style of speaking switches the usual order of words. I means to express that *DELETE has no body* and pushed together *no* and *body* for better effect. After that, I changed the order. [Yoda lingo](https://www.yodaspeak.co.uk/index.php).

Answer (score 1):

What about defining your `post_jobs_id` in your url? And after that get the `id` in your backend.

For example, you can define :

```
DeleteRequestToAPI(post_jobs_id:string) {
    const url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employer/post_jobs/${post_jobs_id}`;
    return this.http.delete(url, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    })
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the best approach for me in using searchParams.

```
    let url = new URL( this.baseUrl + '/*******');
        url.searchParams.append('llC', llC.toString());
        url.searchParams.append('ulC', ulC.toString());
return this.http.delete(url.toString());
```

and on the server side you can get

```
   let data = req.query;
   data['ulC'] ;
   data['llC'] ;
```

This method works for delete as well as get options!

Answer (score -5):

if your back end is Node and express

**router.delete('/post_jobs/:id',(req,res)=>{ let post_jobs_id = req.params.id })**